# Vue component issue with moving through array

Tags: vuejs2

I am and new to vuejs and still learning right now I have 4 components which as far as I can see I can pass data from the parent component to the child and from child to parent. The issue that I am having is with my child component SingleView I have buttons in that component that I am emiting the event to the parent ImageSection to step through the fileList array It works but the issue is that I have to click an extra time in both moving forward and backward through the fileList Array.

When I watch it in the vue dev tools it goes -1, 0 , 1, 2, when I have only 3 files in the array when moving to the previous file it goes 3, 2, 1, 0 then errors out cause the button does not disable at the beginning or end of the array which is another issue Im working on.

I do not understand why I am getting the extra button click when stepping though the array ?

my code as follows

ImageSection.vue

```
<template>
<div id="imageContainer">
  <app-actionbar :file-list="fileList" :current-position="currentPosition"></app-actionbar>
  <app-image-section-single-view
    v-on:updateFileList="onUpdateFileList"
    :fileList="fileList"
    :currentPosition="currentPosition"></app-image-section-single-view>

</div>
</template>

<script>
  import Actionbar from "../Actionbar/Actionbar";
  import ImageSectionSingleView from "./ImageSectionSingleView";
  import {eventBus} from "../../main";

    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          fileList: [],
          currentPosition: 0
        }
      },
      methods: {
        onUpdateFileList(files){
          this.fileList.push.apply(this.fileList,
            ([...files].map((f) => ({
              name: f.name,
              data: URL.createObjectURL(f),
              type: f.type
            }))));
        },
      },
      created() {
        eventBus.$on('moveToNextFile', (positionNext) =>{
           this.currentPosition  = positionNext++ ;
        });
        eventBus.$on('moveToPreviousFile', (positionPrevious) => {
          this.currentPosition = positionPrevious--;
        });
      },
      components: {
        appActionbar: Actionbar,
        appImageSectionSingleView: ImageSectionSingleView
      }
    }
</script>
```

ImageSectionSingleView.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="drop display-inline align-center" @dragover.prevent @drop="onDrop">
    <div class="display-inline">
      <img v-if="fileList.length > 0" :src="fileList[currentPosition].data" class="img" />
      <img v-else src="../../assets/logo.png" class="img" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      props: {
        fileList: { type: Array },
        currentPosition: { type: Number}
      },
      methods:{
        onDrop: function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
          this.$emit('updateFileList', e.dataTransfer.files);
        }
      },
    }
</script>
```

ActionBar.vue

```
<template>
<div class="actionbar image-control">
  <div id="singleview" v-if="display === 'single'">
    <app-single-view :currentPosition="currentPosition" :fileList="fileList" @clicked="displayBar"></app-single-view>
  </div>
  <div id="gridview" v-else>
    <app-grid-view @clicked="displayBar"></app-grid-view>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  import Gridview from "./Gridview.vue";
  import Singleview from "./Singleview.vue";

    export default {
      data: function(){
        return{
          display: 'single'
        }
      },
      props:{
        currentPosition: { type: Number },
        fileList: { type: Array }
      },
      methods: {
       displayBar(value){
         this.display = value;
       }
      },
      components: {
        'app-grid-view': Gridview,
        'app-single-view': Singleview
      }
    }

</script>
```

SingleView.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="icon-container">
    <span class="nav-icons">
      <label class="icon button" @click="movePrevious" :disabled="disablePrevious" id="btnPrevious"><icon-base title="Previous Image" view-box="0 0 512 512"><icon-previous/></icon-base></label>
      <label class="icon button" @click="moveNext" :disabled="disableNext" id="btnNext"><icon-base title="Next Image" view-box="0 0 512 512"><icon-next/></icon-base></label>
    </span>
    <span class="iconbtn-container">
      <label for="fileselect" id="btnAttach" class="icon button"><icon-base title="New" view-box="0 0 448 512" color="green"><IconAttach/></icon-base></label>
      <input type="file" id="fileselect" @change="processFile($event)" hidden>
      <label class="icon button" id="btnExport"><icon-base title="Export image" view-box="0 0 384 512"><icon-export/></icon-base></label>
      <label class="icon button" id="btnDelete"><icon-base title="Delete image" view-box="0 0 384 512"><icon-delete/></icon-base></label>
      <span class="seperator"></span>
      <label class="icon button" @click="switchGridView" id="btnSingleView"><icon-base title="Single View" view-box="0 0 100 125"><icon-single-view/></icon-base></label>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import IconBase from "../icons/base/IconBase.vue";
  import IconAttach from "../icons/IconAttach.vue";
  import IconDelete from "../icons/IconTrash.vue";
  import IconExport from "../icons/IconExport.vue";
  import IconPrevious from "../icons/IconPrevious.vue";
  import IconNext from "../icons/IconNext.vue";
  import IconSingleView from "../icons/IconSingleView";
  import {eventBus} from "../../main";

  export default {
      components: {
        IconBase,
        IconAttach,
        IconDelete,
        IconExport,
        IconPrevious,
        IconNext,
        IconSingleView,
      },
      data(){
        return {
          currentPosition: 0,
          fileList: []
        }
      },
      methods: {
        processFile(event){
          this.fileData = event.target.files[0];
          console.log(this.fileData);
        },
        switchGridView(event){
          this.$emit('clicked','grid')
        },
        movePrevious(){
          eventBus.$emit('moveToPreviousFile', this.currentPosition--);
        },
        moveNext(){
          eventBus.$emit('moveToNextFile', this.currentPosition++);
        },
        disablePrevious(){
          return this.currentPosition >= this.fileList.length - 1;
        },
        disableNext(){
          return this.currentPosition <= 0;
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you increment and decrement current position in two places?

Comment: It was an Error I actually resolved the issue .

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved , I had to pass the data property to the children as props then used those props accordingly .